# Python (xml.etree) not reading XML text

Tags: python, xml

I've not worked with XML before, but am having trouble with getting text out of the following XML:

```
<w>
  <shortening>n</shortening>
  ūmi 
  <mor type="mor">
    <mw>
      [extra stuff]
    </mw>
    <menx>rest</menx>
    <menx>sleep</menx>
    <gra type="gra" relation="ROOT" head="0" index="1"/>
  </mor>
</w>
```

The `Element.text` property corresponding to the `w` tag doesn't have the text ūmi inside, instead it has `None`. I think this is because it is preceded by the `<shortening>` tag. This shouldn't be a Unicode issue, because there are plenty of other Unicode characters that read just fine (this is transliterated Hebrew).

Is there an easy way to fix this? Is this malformed XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that text itself isn't being part of any node. It's the text of an attribute **[tail](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail)** for the tag before it, you can access it with **shortening** node, see this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from StringIO import StringIO

s = '''<w>
  <shortening>n</shortening>
  ūmi 
  <mor type="mor">
    <mw>
      [extra stuff]
    </mw>
    <menx>rest</menx>
    <menx>sleep</menx>
    <gra type="gra" relation="ROOT" head="0" index="1"/>
  </mor>
</w>'''

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(s))
root = tree.getroot()

for i in root.iter('shortening'):
    print i.tail
```

Results:

```
  ūmi
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had tried looking in the `w` element itself's tail, but didn't realise it would attach to the `shortening` element.

Comment: @Kyle_S-C, yes it's sometimes got missed. You cannot access from `w` as it's the root element already, I've provided the link for **tail** that you can read more about ;)